# Passing a different ViewModel to an include layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

I'm including a layout passing a viewmodel:

```
<include
    layout="@layout/user_login"
    app:model="@{model}" />
```

My goal is to use this include in different places passing a **different ViewModel** too.

For example I would like to pass: **UserViewModel** in one place, in another place **InformationViewModel**.
Can I do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here is the component class

```
class SomeComponent(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : FrameLayout(context, attrs) {

    private var mBinding: SomeLayoutBinding? = null

    init {
        if (isInEditMode) {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.some_layout, this, false)
            addView(view)
        } else {
            mBinding = SomeLayoutBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this, true)
        }
    }

    fun setVm(vm: InformationViewModel) {
        mBinding!!.vm = vm
        mBinding!!.executePendingBindings()
    }
}
```

Here is the layout for component

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="vm"
            type="yourpackage.InformationViewModel" />
    </data>

</layout>
```

Here is the way how you set vm

```
 <yourpackage.SomeComponent
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:vm="@{item}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. The goal here is to pass a different ViewModel to the layout, example: app:vm="@{informationViewModel}"  or I can pass app:vm="@{userViewModel}"

Comment: @zerstoer if you wanna to do that you need to create "ParentVm" and here you can put both of vms. Then "app:vm="@{parent.user}" . It's that what you searching for?

Comment: I just want to be able to pass a view model to the include layout. This way the layout will get it and bind the click function from the view model to the buttons onClick. But the viewmodel cannot be always the same viewmodel.